# Evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2x-1}{3x+2}\right)^x$.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I have been trying to solve this limit but i think it doesnt get me anywhere.

I tried with ln(y) but nothing.

I tried to transform it to inf/inf but no result .

Can anyone please help me find it out?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2x-1}{3x+2}\right)^x$$

Comment: Try the "squeeze theorem" with something like $0.9^x$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach. For $x\gt\frac12$
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{2x-1}{3x+2}\right)^x
&=\left(\frac{2-\frac1x}{3+\frac2x}\right)^x\\
&\le\left(\frac23\right)^x
\end{align}
$$
Now the limit as $x\to\infty$ is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Following your idea we have

$$\left(\frac{x-1}{3x+2}\right)^x=e^{x\log \left(\frac{x-1}{3x+2}\right)}\to 0$$

indeed

$$\log \left(\frac{x-1}{3x+2}\right)\to \log \left(\frac13\right) <0 \implies x\log \left(\frac{x-1}{3x+2}\right) \to -\infty$$

or simply

$$\frac{x-1}{3x+2}\sim \frac13 \implies \left(\frac{x-1}{3x+2}\right)^x\sim \frac1{3^x}\to 0$$

or also

$$\left(\frac{x-1}{3x+2}\right)^x=\frac1{3^x}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+2/3}\right)^x=\frac1{3^x}\left(\frac{x+2/3-5/3}{x+2/3}\right)^x=$$$$=\frac1{3^x}\left(1-\frac{5/3}{x+2/3}\right)^x\to 0\cdot e^{-5/3}=0$$

Comment: I still dont get it,maybe because we havent got yet the lessons on "squeeze theorem" ,any other way please would be really helpful 

Comment: @G96 The first one requires the knowledge for $(1+1/x)^x\to e$ the second is straightforward but more obscure, the third one coresponds to your idea and it should be clear to see.

Answer (score 0):

Compute instead the limit of the logarithm and do the substitution $x=1/t$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\left(\left(\frac{2x-1}{3x+2}\right)^x\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(2-t)-\log(3+2t)}{t}
$$
Note that the numerator is negative in a neighborhood of $0$, so the limit is $-\infty$.

Since $\lim_{u\to-\infty}e^u=0$, your given limit is $0$.